# Kafka producer does not signal that all brokers are unreachable

Tags: apache-kafka

When all brokers/node of a cluster are unreachable, the error in the Kafka producer callback is a generic "Topic XXX not present in metadata after 60000 ms".
When I activate the DEBUG log level, I can see that all attempts to deliver the message to any node are failing:

```
DEBUG org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient - Initialize connection to node node2.url:443 (id: 2 rack: null) for sending metadata request
DEBUG org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient - Initiating connection to node node2.url:443 (id: 2 rack: null) using address node2.url:443/X.X.X.X:443
....
DEBUG org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient - Disconnecting from node 2 due to socket connection setup timeout. The timeout value is 16024 ms.
DEBUG org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient - Initialize connection to node node0.url:443 (id: 0 rack: null) for sending metadata request
DEBUG org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient - Initiating connection to node node0.url:443 (id: 0 rack: null) using address node0.url:443/X.X.X.X:443
....
DEBUG org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient - Disconnecting from node 0 due to socket connection setup timeout. The timeout value is 17408 ms.
```

and so on, until, after the deliver timeout, the send() Callback gets the error:

```
ERROR my.kafka.SenderClass - Topic XXX not present in metadata after 60000 ms.
```

Unlike bootstrap url, *all* nodes could be unreachable for example for wrong DNS entries or whatever.
How can the application understand that all nodes were not reachable? This is traced just as DEBUG info and is not avialable to the producer send() callback.
Such an error detail at application level would speed up troubleshoooting.

This error is usually signaled by standard webservice SOAP/REST interface.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The producer only cares about the cluster Controller for bootstrapping and the leaders of the partitions it needs to write to (one of those leaders could be the Controller). That being said, it doesn't need to know about "all" brokers.

> How can the application understand that all nodes were not reachable?

If you set `acks=1` or `acks=all`, then the callback should know at least one broker had the data written. If not, there was some error.

You can use an AdminClient outside of the Producer client to describe the topic(s) and fetch metadata about the leader partitions, then use standard TCP socket network requests to try and `ping` those advertised listeners from Java

FWIW, port 443 should ideally be reserved for HTTPS traffic, not Kafka. Kafka is not a REST/SOAP service.